# I have created a simple app, it is working properly but it ia not visible to other,,,

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, iframe, development-environment

App url

http://apps.facebook.com/visitmanipur/

App page

http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/visitmanipur

The app(iframe facebook) is working in my facebook id but it is not working in other id,,, 
What may be the problem behind this,,,

Its saying... The page you requested was not found.
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.

Comment: Are you sure you have your namespace set?

Comment: Have you got an ssl cert? If not and the person is browsing over https they might not see it. Have you actually uploaded your files to a server (i.e you don't have a hosts file redirect in place confusing you) sounds simple but we all make mistakes :) Is your app in sandbox mode in the developer settings?

Comment: Are you sure the app isn't still in sandbox mode?

Comment: Thankz all Now it is working fine,,,, I have corrected sandbox

Comment: visit my app http://apps.facebook.com/visitmanipur/

Answer (score 0):

As you clarified in the comments, you had forgotten to remove the app from sandbox mode. This prevents non-developers of the app from seeing it